# How to prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{1000}}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{1000}}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}=0$

I mean it's kind of obvious, but how do I prove it correctly?

Comment: You could use that $\frac{n^{1000}}{n^{\sqrt{n}}} = e^{\left(1000-\sqrt{n}\right)\ln n}$.

Comment: L'Hopitals rule repeatedly applied 1001 times makes the numerator 0, and the denominator nonzero, so the limit definitely converges to 0

Comment: I thought about that too :D. But Jacob, look at the tags! :D

Comment: Oh yeah, woops, but why not use l'Hopitals?

Comment: I guess it's neater without using l'hopital every time.

Answer (score 9):

Hint. If $n\geq 1001^2$ then
$$0\leq \frac{n^{1000}}{n^{\sqrt{n}}}\leq \frac{n^{1000}}{n^{1001}}=\frac{1}{n}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a small hint: if $n >  1001^2$ then $\displaystyle \frac{n^{1000}}{n^{\sqrt{n}}} < \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 2):

Try writing it in exponent form
$$
\frac{n^{1000}}{n^{\sqrt{n}}} = \frac{e^{1000 \ln(n)}}{e^{\sqrt{n} \ln(n)}}
= e^{1000 \ln(n) - \sqrt{n} \ln(n)} = e^{(1000 - \sqrt{n}) \ln(n)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Prove that if $0 < \epsilon$, then for all $n > \max(2000000, 1/\epsilon)$ that $|f(n)| < \epsilon$.